# Covert a Flash video stream to HTML

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to convert a flash player embedded video (used for a live streaming) into another type of player.

The problem with flash is simple, it is not supported on smartphones...

The video I'm trying to embed will be very similar to this one

https://live.fmach.it/videos/video/815/

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: That video you posted loads just fine on iOS, so it’s already done I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream that page is using is RTMP tunneled via HTTP (RTMPT).  Browsers can't connect to RTMP servers, nor can they play FLV video which is what is sent over RTMP.

If you wish to play this stream, you'll have to convert it to something else, such as WebM.  You can use FFmpeg for this.